# How to group 'like' with Codeigniter active records?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm building a search form with multiple options. The idea is to look for people with certain characteristics like career, name of last company job, years of experience, etc.

In the first part of the form you can enter a career you would like candidate to have, on second part you can enter one or more companies name. What I want is my query to look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM work_experience
WHERE position = 'some position'
AND (company LIKE 'company 1' OR company LIKE 'company 2', etc)
```

Problem is I don't know hoy many company names the user might enter, what I do is store every name in an array which I don't know how big it may be.

I tried using or_like() active record, but the problem was that it looked for people with 'positionx' OR people working at 'company x' which is not the result I want.

Is there a way to make this query using active records? Or even how can I make the query in simple SQL if I don't know the exact number of company names I'm searching for.

Thank you for your time and help, if something was not clear please let me know.

Comment: why don't you use where_in if you have to check on multiple values.let me know if you need further info.

Comment: I need further info :( how can I use where_in?

Comment: @Zeeshan just read documentation, where_in sounds good but problem is user won't input exactly the company name as it is stored. For example, candidate may have stored 'google' as company, and user searches for 'Google'. That's why I was using 'like'.

Comment: if you are taking company name in full similar to your example where_in will work but if you want to check for something like this : goog is searched then it should go for google if google is the company starting in such sequence.

Here what matters is how you are taking the details in your search form.what i would suggest you is rather than taking input through input text take it via checkboxes as that would make your life easier and you would good practice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it should be -

**View:**

```
<form action="/career/search/" method="POST">
      Position: <input type="text" name="position" />
      Company1: <input type="text" name="company[]" />
      Company2: <input type="text" name="company[]" />
      Company3: <input type="text" name="company[]" />
      ...
      ...
      CompanyN: <input type="text" name="company[]" />
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
class Career extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function search()
    {
       $this->career_model->search_career($this->input->post());
    }
}
```

**(A) Model (using where_in):**

```
class Career_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function search_career($data)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('position', $data['position']);
        $this->db->where_in('company', $data['company']);
        $query = $this->db->get('work_experience');

        echo "<pre>"; print_r($query->result());   // Result           
    }
}
```

**(B) Model (using or_like):**

```
class Career_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function search_career($data)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('position', $data['position']);

        foreach($data['company'] as $company)
        {
            $this->db->or_like('company', $company);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get('work_experience');

        echo "<pre>"; print_r($query->result());   // Result           
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

```
foreach($data['company'] as $company)
{
    $wh[] = "`company` LIKE '".$company."'";
}
$where = "(".implode("or", $wh).")";
$this->db->where($where, NULL, FALSE);
```

Comment: yes that is good solution, problem is the user may type the company name different from what it is stored in database. For example, if person stored her last company name as 'google inc' and user types 'Google' it won't show. That is why I was using 'like'.

Comment: Yes this works, I just tried it. Is there a way this can work but instead of using where(position) I can use like(position)?

Comment: Yaah ofcourse. Just replace this `$this->db->where('position', $data['position']);` with this `$this->db->like('position', $data['position']);`. Thats it!

Comment: Just realized that it looks for a person who either has 'positionX' or works for 'companyZ', so if I look for an asistant from IBM or Google, I get an asistant from IBM, and other people who happened to work at Google.

Comment: Exactly, thats what it'll give. I guess it your expected result.

Comment: Oh no, I'm sorry if it wasn't clear. That's why I put parenthesis in the original sql. In the example I was talking about, it should only give as result for person who is an asistant AND works for either google or IBM.

Comment: Check edits. It kinda hacky, but should work. Replace the `foreach loop` with edits.

Comment: one small question, since with the NULL and FALSE at the WHERE clause, it will tell CI not to protect the field. Is this open to SQL injection or other vulnerabilities?

Comment: Glad you asked. If you are using active records, you don't have to worry about SQL injections since codeigniter `auto escapes` the value. So the answer of your question is NO.

Comment: Read the NOTE (in red box) here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html. Just below the title `$this->db->where();`

Answer (score 2):

Try using this sequence

Controller Code

```
$getcompanyList=$this->input->post('company'); //post variable company from view
$data['companyList']=explode(',', $getcompanyList);
//Query for model
$getResult=$this->myModel->somefunction($data);
```

Model Code

```
function somefunction($data){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('position','some position');
$this->db->where_in('company',$data['companyList']);
//or $this->db->or_where_in('company',$data['companyList']);
$getResult=$this->db->get('work_experience');
}
```

Now if you doesn't get the desired result then just print the last query using $this->db->last_query() or do profiling of your application and check what sql is being generated.

Comment: How can I loop the or_like? I don't know exactly how many companies there will be.

Comment: user types in a form the companies he is looking for, separated by a comma. I then store each company in an array. Then I look in Database for companies the user entered.

Comment: Ok.. so you are taking companies list in textbox(preferably seprated via some seprater like comma[,]) then just take it as $this->input->post('company') and then explode and convert it in to array and in model use where_in clause($this->db->where_in('company',$companyArray))

Comment: @k10gaurav What in the world are you talking about?

Comment: @ParagTyagi User has entered company name in the textbox separated by comma in view, now when it comes to controller then it has been converted to array and array has been passed to model for checking.